# 5 sized box in flutter and get error button overflow flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

[image]I have 5 sizedBox and each sizedbox has many widgets,sizedboxes are inside a container inside scaffold, when I run my application, got an message in emulator that :

```
Column(
children:[
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...

],

),
```

Its one of my sized box

```
    return Scaffold(
    // resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
    appBar: AppBar(
      backgroundColor: ColorManager.mainDarkPrimary,
      title: const Text(AppStrings.appName),
    ),
    body: Column(
      children: [
        Container(
          height: 200,
          decoration: BoxDecoration(
            borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
              bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
            ),
            color: ColorManager.darkPrimary,
          ),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              Positioned(
                top: 80,
                right: 0,
                child: Container(
                  height: 80,
                  width: 300,
                  decoration: BoxDecoration(
                    color: ColorManager.white,
                    borderRadius: const BorderRadius.only(
                      topLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                      bottomLeft: Radius.circular(50),
                    ),
                  ),
                ),
              ),
              Positioned(
                top: 105,
                right: 40,
                child: Text(
                  AppStrings.appShorDescription,
                  style: TextStyle(
                      fontSize: FontSize.s20, color: ColorManager.darkGrey),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
        SizedBox(
          height: height * 0.05,
        ),
        Column(
          children: [  
SizedBox(
              height: 110,
              child: Stack(
                clipBehavior: Clip.none,
                children: [
                  Positioned(
                    top: 35,
                    right: 20,
                    child: Material(
                      child: Container(
                        height: 75.0,
                        width: width * 0.9,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                          color: ColorManager.white,
                          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(0.0),
                          boxShadow: [
                            BoxShadow(
                                color: ColorManager.grey,
                                offset: const Offset(-10.0, 10.0),
                                blurRadius: 20.0,
                                spreadRadius: 4.0),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                    top: 0,
                    right: 30,
                    child: Card(
                      elevation: 10.0,
                      shadowColor: ColorManager.grey,
                      shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
                        borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
                      ),
                      child: Container(
                        height: 65,
                        width: 65,
                        decoration: BoxDecoration(
                            borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                            image: DecorationImage(
                                fit: BoxFit.fill,
                                image: AssetImage(
                                    AppStrings.mozafatiDatesUrl))),
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
                  Positioned(
                      top: 50,
                      right: 120,
                      // ignore: sized_box_for_whitespace
                      child: Container(
                        height: 60,
                        width: 160,
                        child: Column(
                          crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                          children: [
                            (Text(
                              AppStrings.mozafatiDatesName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: FontSize.s16,
                                  color: ColorManager.darkGrey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeightManager.bold),
                            )),
                            (Text(
                              AppStrings.mozafatiDatesName,
                              style: TextStyle(
                                  fontSize: FontSize.s12,
                                  color: ColorManager.darkGrey,
                                  fontWeight: FontWeightManager.bold),
                            )),
                            Divider(
                              color: ColorManager.darkPrimary,
                            ),
                          ],
                        ),
                      ))
                ],
              ),
            ),
```

> button overflow flutter
> , a renderFlex overfloed by 146 pixels on the buttom

how can I place 5 sizedbox in scroll

Comment: Can you show us your code?

Comment: @sunny Try to wrap the widget  with an `Expanded` widget

Comment: Updated my question again

Comment: What the end result should look like?

Comment: @sunny Can you share the parent widget? so the widget above the `Column`

Comment: As you see my code is from "scaffold(...)"

Answer (score 3):

Make your `Column` scrollable by wrapping it with a `SingleChildScrollView`:

```dart
SingleChildScrollView(
        child: Column(
            children: [SizedBox(), SizedBox()])
    )
```

Answer (score 1):

```
 return Scaffold(
      body: Container(
        child: ListView(
          shrinkWrap: true,
          children: [
            SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(),
            SizedBox(),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Comment: not work for my code

Answer (score 0):

You can wrap Column with SingleChildScrollView widget

```
SingleChildScrollView(child:Column(
children:[
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...
SizedBox(...

],

),)
```

Comment: its not work for my code